# how to set at runtime the column type of datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, runtime, datagridviewcolumn

I want to set the **DisplayStyle** of column 1 in my datagridview to "**DropDownButton**" with collection of ITEMS "A","B","C" and "D" at runtime. I tried below code also.. but it did not work :

```
 DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
            comboCell.Items.Add("A");
            comboCell.Items.Add("B");
            comboCell.Value = "A";

 dgv.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle = comboCell;
```

and this displaystyle should be for columns/rows in datagridview.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

In design time of your DataGrid, you should leave adding column1. You can add the Comb box column at run time as following.

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
col.Name = "cboColumn";
col.Items.Add("A");
col.Items.Add("B");
dgv.Columns.Add(col);
if (dgv.CurrentRow != null)
    dgv.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value = "A";
```